# groupby with value masking

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, mask

I have a data set  name history contain columns : year ,region , number of item sold
and i would like to know which region have items sold higher than the mean of items sold that year
my code look like

```
         (history['region','year','item sold'].group-by(['year','region']).mean()))
```

I would like to mask out all the region has mean value of item sold than the mean of the year
as year region mean of the region

Answer (score 0):

here is pesudo code how you can do it using lambda function. lambda function will filter group rows which has "item sold" value greater than mean of that group

```py
history['region','year','item sold'].groupby(['year','region']).apply(lambda g:\
g[g['item sold']>g['item sold'].mean()])
```

Comment: can you share a portion of your dataframe to test this